# PHP POST Method is not throwing or sending variables

Tags: php, post, get

For example this is my Table:

```html
Table [category]

[categoryID]    [name]
    1            Home
    2            About
    3            Contact
```

What I want to do is when I select the `Home` with categoryID of `1` and pressed the button. It will load into a page `load.php?categoryID=1`. How can I do that? Below is my code:

```html
<?php if(isset($_POST['update'])){
   $categoryID = $_POST['categoryID'];
}

?>
<form class="add-new-post" method="post" action="load.php?categoryID=<?php echo $categoryID ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Choose Category: 
   <select name="categoryID" >
    <?php do { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $editcat_rs['categoryID']; ?>">
    <?php echo $editcat_rs['name']; ?></option> 
    <?php } while ($editcat_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($editcat_query));?>
   </select>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Post</button>
</form>
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: url?variable1=value1&variable2=value2... is GET not POST. So you need to use $_GET instead of $_POST.

Comment: So I used the GET method now. Somehow I managed to get what I want. This is the result `load.php?categoryID=27&update=`. But my another problem is. Where dit `&update` came from? Thank you for the helm!

Comment: `&update` is the "name" of the button and is submitted with the form. It has no value (thus `&update=`), but it could be used in a situation where there are multiple buttons, then the php could detect which button was clicked.

Comment: `&update` is coming from your submit button and you don't need to post it you can justsend i through simple `<a href="load.php?categoryID=27>` tag

Comment: is there a way to remove it after clicking the button so that it will only show `load.php?categoryID=27`? Thanks!

Comment: You could set the form method to $_POST, use post to get the details and then the fact update gets send along doesn't matter. Or you could use a link (see one comment above) to simply send the category ID rather than the entire form.